# Jquery add class after page reloads

Tags: jquery

I want to add a CSS class after the page has been loaded or refreshed:

**JS**

```
$(".download-title a").on("click",function() {
    $(this).addClass('.current');
    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="download-title">
    <a href="www.mylink1.com/apple">apple</a>
</div>
<div class="download-title">
     <a href="www.mylink1.com/Orange">orange</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're adding an additional dot to this part:

```
$(this).addClass('.current');
```

It should be:

```
$(this).addClass('current');
```

Otherwise, it seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/ytgmm5b9/2/

The additional dot may be why you think it's not working. You're adding a class you didn't have styling for.

Comment: It's `addClass`, you are also missing a `'`

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the missing '. Thanks for informing me of addClass. Can't believed I missed that.

Comment: after page reloads the active class will be gone

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(document).ready(function (){ // your add css class })` to throw the event after the page load.

Comment: after reloads the active class will gone